# How to select a range in column A that parallel to selected range (the selected range is Non-Contiguous range) without Looping

Tags: vba, excel

If the selected range is `Rng1 = C1:D2,C4:D5` , the result range must be `Rng2 = A1:A2,A4:A5` .

I use two ways that work fine if `Rng1` is Contiguous but both not work if `Rng1` is Non-Contiguous range:

```
Sub test()
  Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
  Set Rng1 = Range("C1:D2,C4:D5")
'first way:
   Set Rng2 = Rng1.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 1 - Rng1.Column)
'second way:
  Set Rng2 = Range(Cells(Rng1(1).Row, 1), Cells(Rng1(Rng1.Count).Row, 1))
  Rng2.Select
End Sub
```

So can we do that without looping through `Rng1` Rows or Areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub test()
  Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
  Set Rng1 = Range("C1:D2,C4:D5")
  Set Rng1 = Rng1.EntireRow

  Set Rng2 = Intersect(Rng1, Rng1.Parent.Columns(1))

End Sub
```